# searching for a string in a url

Tags: java, string, url, search

I'm trying to search for a particular string inside of my company's website in order to check that the website is alive. 
Can you give me a hint on how to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

try {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://10.200.10.199:80");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                oracle.openStream()));
    inputLine = in.readLine();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println("Page was not found - might not be running");
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you run the code?  Do you see any output?  If you are getting an exception then I'd print it out or at least the message.

Comment: Any particular reason you're reinventing the wheel? Why not run something like Icinga: https://www.icinga.org/?

Comment: The program is running and printing the data from the web page. Now i want to check if a string exists in the data recieved. ddrace - I'm doing this project on my free will and want to learn by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringUtils from org.apache.commons.lang (Commons Lang) can do the job well for you.

```
boolean contains=false;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    contains = StringUtils.contains(inputLine, searchString);
}
```

You can rather use String.contains(CharSequence) too. CharSequence can be created easily by

```
CharSequence cs = searchString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like regular expressions to me. Unless you know the string exactly, in which case you could just do String.indexOf on each line.